# Codeigniter email library sending blank emails or html source code

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-email

I've never had issues sending emails before through CodeIgniter, but all of a sudden it's an issue on my latest project.

I'm using this [mail server tool](https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) to send mail on my local-host, which has never given me any issues before, and then the CodeIgniter email library.

**I can get one of 2 results:** either the email sends, but all the raw HTML source code is displayed, or the email sends and has a subject line, but the entire body is blank.

**This is my `email_helper.php`**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

function send_email($to, $subject, $template)
{
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('email');

    $config = array(
      'mailtype'  => 'html',
      'newline' => '\r\n',
      'crlf'  => '\r\n'
    );

    //If I comment out this line, it sends raw HTML, otherwise it sends a blank body.
    $ci->email->initialize($config);

    $ci->email->from($ci->config->item('from_email_address'), $ci->config->item('from_email_name'));
    $ci->email->reply_to($ci->config->item('from_email_address'), $ci->config->item('from_email_name'));
    $ci->email->to($to);

    $ci->email->subject($subject);
    $ci->email->message($ci->load->view('email/' . $template . '_html', $data, TRUE));
    $ci->email->send();
}
```

**this is my `test_html.php`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Test</title></head>
  <body>
      <div style="max-width: 800px; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0;">
       TEST!
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then I'm calling the email helper from my controller with this:

```
$this->load->helper('email_helper');
send_email($this->input->post('email'), 'Test Subject', 'test');
```

Comment: try without doctype and eventually head tag

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You r missing `$data` there in your load view section and also try with `$ci->load->library('email', $config);` instead of `$ci->email->initialize($config);`*

`send_email` should be like this :

```
function send_email($to, $subject, $template)
{
    $ci = & get_instance();

    $config = array(
      'mailtype'  => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'newline' => '\r\n',
      'crlf'  => '\r\n'
    );

    $data = '';

    $body = $ci->load->view('email/' . $template . '_html', $data, TRUE);
    echo $body; die;

    $ci->load->library('email', $config);
    $ci->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $ci->email->from($ci->config->item('from_email_address'), $ci->config->item('from_email_name'));
    $ci->email->reply_to($ci->config->item('from_email_address'), $ci->config->item('from_email_name'));
    if ($to) 
    {
      $ci->email->to($to);

      $ci->email->subject($subject);
      $ci->email->message($body);
      if ($ci->email->send())
      {
        return TRUE;
      }
      else
      {
        echo $ci->email->print_debugger();die;
      }
    }
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: there aren't any errors, it sends successfully, but the body is still blank.

Comment: what you get when `echo $body; die;`

Comment: In chrome dev tools i can see the rendered HTML when I echo the body. So that piece seems to be working right.

Comment: ok try with adding this `$ci->email->set_mailtype("html");` before `$ci->email->to($to);`

Comment: it worked! I can't believe it! Why would it not work when setting mailtype in the config array, but it would work directly?? Maybe a bug in the CI mail class?

Comment: not sure its a bug but may be depends upon ci version environment, Updated my answer,

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green and do up vote also